# Flying Saucer: Convert Multiple Html to 1 PDF document

Tags: java, itext, flying-saucer

I have an Report template which is comprised with 4 HTML file. Let say

1. p1.html
2. p2.html
3. p3.html
4. p4.html

I parse each page  separately using Flying Saucer and replace the place holder using velocity and convert it to pdf sucessfully. Now the problem is to convert these 4 HTML pages to a single pdf document.

There are 2 ways to do achieve that.

### Merging HTML

By merging all HTML document and then populating the placeholder using velocity which is being done successfully but problem arises in pagination. I want each HTML page converted to 1 pdf page but in this scenario all text are merged.

### Merge  PDF after Conversion

This approach doesn't seem right to me because generating each PDF page separately from respective HTML page and then merging to 1 pdf document is not an enhance-able solution.

Your suggestions with coding examples will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can use [CSS `page-break-before` or `page-break-after`](http://flyingsaucerproject.github.io/flyingsaucer/r8/guide/users-guide-R8.html#xil_37) to break pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opted for merging HTML templates and used following CSS to paginate it where it is required.

```
    <style type="text/css"> 
    @page { size:letter; padding:0; margin:0.5in 25px 100px 25px;}
    *{ font-family: "verdana", tahoma, arial, sans-serif;}
     table { -fs-table-paginate: paginate; thead {
    display:table-header-group;}}
    @page {
         @top-center { content: element(header) }
    }
    @page:first {
        margin:30px 25px 100px 25px;
         @top-center { content: element() }
    }
    table.header {
        height:100px;
        display: block; text-align: center; 
        position: running(header);
    }
    div.footer {
        display: block; text-align: center;
        position: running(footer);
    }
    div.content {page-break-after: always;}

     #footer {
    position: running(footer);
    text-align: right;
    }

    #pagenumber:before {
    content: counter(page);  }

    #pagecount:before {
    content: counter(pages);  }


</style>
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm looking for a way to combine documents too.

I do know how to start new pages while using a single HTML document though. Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        @page { /* default page styles here */

        @page p1 { /* page template for first document */ }
        @page p2 { /* page template for second document */ }
        @page p3 { /* page template for third document */ }
        @page p4 { /* page template for fourth document */ }

        #p1 { page: p1; } /* tells #p1 to use p1 page template */
        #p2 { page: p2; } /* tells #p2 to use p2 page template */
        #p3 { page: p3; } /* tells #p3 to use p3 page template */
        #p4 { page: p4; } /* tells #p4 to use p4 page template */
    </style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

    <article id="p1">
        <!-- page 1 content here -->
    </article>

    <article id="p2">
        <!-- page 2 content here -->
    </article>

    <article id="p3">
        <!-- page 3 content here -->
    </article>

    <article id="p4">
        <!-- page 4 content here -->
    </article>

</html>
```

My understanding is that when an element requires a different page template, then a page break will get added in.

If you don't need different page templates (the headers, footers, etc. are all the same) then you can probably just ask for a page break for each article:

```
article { page-break-before: always; }
```